# Google Play Game Services, Android, accepting quests in Play Gams app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm working through the [Quality Checklist for Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#9_events_and_quests)

Under point 9.2

> Allow players to accept quests from the Play Games app.
>
> Your game must bring up a view to allow players to accept a quest when they click on a quest tile in the Play Games app.

I go into the Play Games app. I find my game. I see the Quests tab, I open that. I see a list of quests. On each quest tile, it says "Play".

Now, this quality checklist wants me to bring up a specific view when they get into the game that allows the quest to be accepted.

I can't find *anything* pertaining to specifically showing a view like this. I haven't spotted any special information in the Intent that's used to launch my app.

- [Quality Checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist)
- [Quests API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/quest/package-summary.html)
- [Events and Quests in Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quests)

How do I go about figuring out that you came into my game from a specific quest tile in the Play Games app?

Or can I explicitly set a different Activity to be fired from those quest tiles?

Answer (score 1):

We spent a few hours for the same question and the answer was simple.

Just use
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks

and callback registration
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#registerConnectionCallbacks(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks)

```
    gameHelper.getApiClient().registerConnectionCallbacks(
    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            // If the game started via Accept quest button in Google Play Games,
            // we will got here a bundle with all information
            if (bundle == null)
                return;

            QuestEntity questEntity = bundle.getParcelable(Games.Quests.EXTRA_QUEST);

            if (questEntity == null)
                return;

           activity.startActivityForResult(Games.Quests.getQuestIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), questEntity.getQuestId()), REQUEST_CODE_QUEST_UI);
       }

       @Override
       void onConnectionSuspended(int cause){}
    });
```